# Connecting table with Organizations with Person, but connect only first person associated with Organization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I want to connect two tables. One Table is Organization, and One is Persons, but with all Organizations I want to use by MSSQL only first person which Is working with organization. I try by "top 1" in sql but I don't have got success. Could You will try to give me a Solution to manage to conect organization with only one first person?

I tried this Solution:

```
  SELECT Org.Org_ID,
      Org.OrgName as 'Nazwa klienta',
      ISNULL(Org.SIC,'') as 'Nazwa skrócona',
      ISNULL( (Org.Address1+', '+ Org.Zip+ ', ' + Org.City),'') as 'Adres',
      Person.LastName as 'Nazwisko',
      Person.FirstName as 'Imię',
      ISNULL(Org.Industry,'') as 'Branża',
      ISNULL(Org.Comments,'') as 'Dostarczane wyroby i usługi' 
FROM 
  Org INNER JOIN Person
  ON Org.Org_ID = Person.Org_ID
WHERE
  Person.Org_ID= (
    SELECT MIN(Person.Org_ID) 
    FROM   Person
    WHERE  Person.Org_ID = Org.Org_ID
  ) and (Org.OrgName IS not NULL)
```

My Schema of Table is that I have got two tables Person and Org, and I tried to connect them by Person.Org_ID and Org.Org_ID.

Comment: Does table Persons have a date which describes when he/she started working? If yes then you'd have to add a subquery to the join statement selecting MIN(Date) and JOIN using that.

Comment: Person and Org table has got a Grid number withis unical values for Org.Org_ID and Person can have got too Person.Org_ID

Comment: So you decide which one was working first based on the lowest number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entire sure I understood the question, but the following may help:

```
SELECT Org.Org_ID,
      Org.OrgName as 'Nazwa klienta',
      ISNULL(Org.SIC,'') as 'Nazwa skrócona',
      ISNULL( (Org.Address1+', '+ Org.Zip+ ', ' + Org.City),'') as 'Adres',
      Person.LastName as 'Nazwisko',
      Person.FirstName as 'Imię',
      ISNULL(Org.Industry,'') as 'Branża',
      ISNULL(Org.Comments,'') as 'Dostarczane wyroby i usługi' 
FROM Org 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Org_ID, LastName, FirstName FROM Person
            WHERE exists (
                SELECT MIN(Person.Org_ID) 
                FROM   Person
                WHERE  Person.Org_ID = Org.Org_ID) ) p
  ON Org.Org_ID = p.Org_ID
WHERE Org.OrgName IS not NULL
```

Note: I modified the query in notepad, so it may need a few tweaks ...

Good luck.